# Does checking a large binary and then deleting it effects repository size permanently?

Tags: git

I had merge request and checked in a build folder containing binaries by mistake, I deleted the build folder and did another commit to remove it from the merge request.
that merge request was merged to master later but I have a debate with colleague who believes, even though i have deleted the binary folder, just because it has been part of my commit history, it will forever increase the size of the repository (master branch). I wonder if that is accurate. thank you

```
git checkout -b somebranch
//did some work 
//created 
git add . 
git commit -m 'xxx'

git push --set-upstream somebranch

rm -rf build/
git add . 
git commit -m 'yyy'
git push
```

somebranch was merged to master

is the size of the repository increased as much as the size of the removed binaries? does this slow down the subsequent cloning of the repo?

Comment: Since you can always checkout older commits, the state at that time has to be in the repository. So yes, those files will always be there, unless you purge all the commits where they exist from history. (And even then they might still be in the reflog until they get cleaned up)

Comment: even if rebased?

Comment: See this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/10362622

Comment: If there is any commit in your history, where the files existed, they are still in the repo. I doubt your rebase got rid of those but only reparented them

Answer (score 3):

> Does checking a large binary and then deleting it effects repository size permanently?

Yes it does. You can always go back to a commit where the file existed and check it out, so `git` needs to save it permanently.

> Is the size of the repository increased as much as the size of the removed binaries?

No. [git usually compresses](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) the contents of files under version control.

> Does this slow down the subsequent cloning of the repo?

Generally yes, but note the possibilty to do "shallow" clones using the [`git clone --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) parameter. This allows you to grab only part of the history of a remote repo, reducing the size on your local drive and increasing performance.

Depending on where in your history the file existed you could use `git rebase` to rewrite the history to have never contained that file. Remember that the actual disk space is only freed some time afterwards when git actually removes the now orphaned object during garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a debate with colleague who believes, even though i have deleted the binary folder, just because it has been part of my commit history, it will forever increase the size of the repository (master branch). I wonder if that is accurate.

Basically yes, it's totally accurate. The fundamental principle of Git is that commits cannot be lost or modified. Therefore if you made a commit that had the big files in it, that commit is still there and by definition so are the big files. Moreover, *every* commit contains *all* the files in the project, so every commit *after* the bad commit *also* has the big files.

So this is not a problem that you can solve just by making some new commits. The way you solve this kind of problem is to run the entire repository through some potentially dangerous tool (such as `filter-repo`) that effectively rewrites the whole repository in a tricky way, manipulating the existing commits in a deep under-the-hood way, ripping out the bad commits and making replacement commits that lack the problematic files.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with [git](/questions/tagged/git), but you said:

> that merge request was merged to master later ...

Git itself does not have anything called "merge requests" (nor "pull requests" for that matter).  Git *does* have merges and the `git merge` command (and also the `git request-pull` command, but this merely makes text suitable for sending as part of an email message: it does no merging).  Git*Lab* offer something called Merge Requests, and other hosting sites offer things called Pull Requests, but we have to guess what you mean here since you have not mentioned GitLab.

What we *can* say, about Git in general, is this:

- If the commit(s) with the large files in them exist, they need space for those files.
- If those commit(s) no longer exist, they don't need space for those files.

So the *Git* answer to whether these:

> forever increase the size of the repository

depends on whether those commits still *exist*.  Answering *that* question is where things get complicated, because MRs and PRs and hosting sites add wrinkles that aren't there in plain Git.

You added this to that last bit:

> (master branch).

The *branch name* isn't really important.  Git isn't about *branches;* it's about *commits*.  We organize our commits into things we call "branches"—the word *branch* is badly overused in Git, almost to the point where it becomes meaningless, but the collections-of-commits form "branches"—and we use *branch names* to find specific important commits, by which we can find the earlier commits that make up these collections that we call "branches".  But at the end of the day, it's really all about the commits.

Each Git commit:

- Is numbered: it has some big ugly hash ID (e.g., `a123456` when shortened).  This hash ID—or more formally, *object ID* or OID—is literally how Git *finds* the commit.  Git *needs* the OID to locate the commit inside its big database of all-of-its-Git-objects.
- Is read-only: no part of *any* commit can ever be changed.
- Stores two things: a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata (information about the commit itself).

The files stored *in* the commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, so that if there are a million commits but all of them just reuse one file over and over again, there's only one copy of that file in the repository.  They *can* share the files like this *because* the objects are all read-only like this.  Since it's impossible to overwrite that object, you can't change the stored file, so it's safe for all the commits to share the file.  But as long as some commit, somewhere in the objects database, has some big file, the *repository* has the file in it, and therefore that file takes (some) space.<sup>1</sup>

The *metadata* in any given commit includes, for Git's own use, the raw hash ID of the *parent* (or parents, plural) of that commit.  This parent linkage forms a backwards-looking chain of commits, which is how "branches" actually work: the branch *name* gives the raw hash ID of the *latest* commit, and from that commit, Git works backwards, one hop at a time, from a child commit to its parent.  That parent is itself a child of another parent (the "grandparent" of the latest commit), and *that* parent has another parent, and so on.  Traversing this list, backwards, one hop at a time, *finds* the history in the repository; the commits *are* the history in the repository, chained together (backwards) via this metadata.

The upshot of all of *that* is straightforward enough: if you have the *latest* commit in a Git repository, you also have *every earlier commit*.  That's because a Git commit automatically brings with it its parent, which automatically brings with it another parent, and so on, all the way back to the start of history.<sup>2</sup>  [This is what perivesta means by this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189118/does-checking-a-large-binary-and-then-deleting-it-effects-repository-size-perman#comment127545838_72189118)

---

<sup>1</sup>The amount of space needed for a file depends heavily on how well it compresses.  Git has two different kinds of compression, too.  As a general rule, these compression techniques work really well on source files made up of human-readable text, not very well on build products, and not at all on pre-compressed files like JPG images or zipped archives or whatever.  But that's a separate issue.

<sup>2</sup>A special kind of clone, a so-called *shallow* clone, omits certain parents at "shallow graft points".  Shallow clones have certain restrictions, so we normally use full (non-shallow) clones.  The repository size you're asking about is that of a non-shallow clone in the first place, so we get to ignore this special case.

---

#### How we get rid of commits

A Git repository is normally built up over time by *adding* commits, one by one, like bricks making up a building.  We never remove a commit: we just add a new one.  Your "commit build products, remove build products, commit again" process made *two* commits, one of which holds the build products and one of which doesn't.  The *second* of these commits *requires the first one* because of the way Git stores commits and metadata.

But sometimes we really do want to *remove* a commit.  We can do that—sort of—using the fact that a *branch name* is *defined* as "contains the hash ID of the latest commit".  When we *add* commits to a repository, Git works like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--somebranch
```

Here, the name `somebranch` *points to* (contains the raw hash ID of) the currently-latest commit `H` (the letter `H` stands in for some actual, random-looking, big ugly hash ID).  Commit `H` points backwards to its parent `G` (the metadata for `H` contains `G`'s hash ID), `G` points backwards to `F`, and so on.

When we make a new commit using commit `H` as the *current* commit, Git stores a new snapshot-and-metadata and sets it up so that the *new* commit points backwards to `H`.  Then Git stores this *new* commit's hash ID into the branch name:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--somebranch
```

where `I` is our new commit.

To *get rid* of commit `I`, and commit `H` too, we can tell Git that it should store the raw hash ID of commit `G` into the name `somebranch`.  When we do that, we get:

```
          H--I   ???
         /
...--F--G   <-- somebranch
```

The *name* `somebranch` now points to `G`, which continues (forever!) to point backwards to `F`.  Commits `H-I` are still *in the database* but nobody can *find* them.

Once we do this kind of thing, Git will *eventually* drop commits `H-I` entirely.  Precisely when and why is complicated, but the key is that there must be *no names by which we can find the hash IDs*.  As long as no name lets us find commit `I`, commit `I` will eventually get tossed out.  As long as commit `I` is being tossed out and it's the only way to find commit `H`, commit `H` will eventually get tossed out too.  Commit `G`, on the other hand, is easily found: the name `somebranch` finds it.  Commit `F` is easily found by starting with the name `somebranch`, which finds `G`, and working backwards.  So commits up through and including `G` won't be tossed out.

This means that we *get rid* of commits, in Git, by re-arranging our branch names (and other names as needed: tag names, remote-tracking names, and any other names that might exist in the repository) such that they *don't* find the commit.  Because commits find earlier commits, though, it's *absolutely necessary* that we strip away *all* commits after some point, in order to strip away that particular commit.  To get rid of commit `H` we *must* get rid of commit `I` too!

Now we can talk about the mechanics involved: what *commands* we use in Git to do this sort of thing.

#### `git reset` and `git branch -f`

If we just want to move some branch name, we can tell Git *move the branch name*.  There are two commands that do this:

- `git branch -f` will let you take any branch name and make it point to *any* commit.  You just supply the name and the hash ID.  But there's one restriction: you can't have this branch checked out.  If you do have the branch checked out, you need the other command.
- `git reset` will let you move the *current* branch name to *any* commit.  You just supply the hash ID.  The current branch moves to point to that hash ID.  You must, however, choose what Git should do with Git's index and your working tree.  (This gets complicated but I'll skip all the details.)

The negative part of doing this, of course, is that we lose all the commits *after* the one we want to drop.  If commit `H` is bad, but commit `I` is good, and we reset or `git branch -f` away commit `H`, we lose commit `I` too.

#### Rebase

The `git rebase` command, especially in its *interactive* rebase form, lets us re-arrange commits however we like.  Now, we already know that it's impossible to *change* any commit, so that's not what rebase does.  Instead, rebase works by *copying* commits.  A rebase operation essentially runs multiple `git cherry-pick` commands, with each cherry-pick being a single-commit-copy step.  So rebase automates these copies.  But it also adds a first and last step.

Suppose we have these commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- some branch
```

and we'd like to *drop* commit `G` entirely, but keep `H` and `I`.  To do that, we need to *copy* `H` and `I` to new-and-improved commits, which we'll call `H'` and `I'`.  These new commits will have new snapshots and new metadata: new commit `H'` will use commit `F` as its parent, and new commit `I'` will use `H'`—the copy of `H`—as its parent, like this:

```
       H'-I'
      /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- somebranch
```

Once we've made these two copies, `git branch -f` (or an equivalent `git reset`) can *move* the name `somebranch` to point to `I'`:

```
       H'-I'  <-- somebranch
      /
...--F--G--H--I   ???
```

which we can draw this way:

```
...--F--H'-I'   <-- somebranch
      \
       G--H--I   ???
```

Git will now—well, eventually—discard the entire `G-H-I` chain, since there's no way to *find* it.  When we look at history, we see commits that look exactly *like* the original `H` and `I`—they make the same *changes* as `H` and `I` did, and have the same log messages—but they have different hash IDs.

#### Merge vs squash-merge

Besides rebasing commits away, there's one other trick we may often use called a *squash merge*.  This one is workflow-dependent: some people love squash merges, some people hate them, some are kind of indifferent, and a very small number of people actually know what they're doing and use them exactly when they're appropriate.

Suppose we have a chain of commits like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We now develop a new feature or two.  I'll draw two features, `br1` and `br2` for now, which will force a true (non-squash, non-fast-forward) merge:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We now decide that we'd like to merge the two feature branches, so we run:

```
git switch br1 && git merge br2
```

to merge `br2` into `br1`.  The result, if all goes well, looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

(`main` still exists and still points to `H`, I just couldn't draw it any more).

We can now *delete* the name `br2`, and make the name `main` point to commit `M` and then delete the name `br1` as well:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

We don't need the other two branch names any more: commit `M`, which has *two* parents, lets us find commits `J` and `L` both, and those let us find `I` and `K`, which let us find `H`, and so on.  So all the history remains intact, and all of it is find-able.

More typically, we might merge *one* feature branch into `main` like this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- main (HEAD)
```

(Doing this in command-line Git requires a flag, `git merge --no-ff`, to prevent Git from doing a fast-forward instead of a merge.  GitHub's green <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button always makes a true merge, as if you always specified `--no-ff`.  GitLab is probably fancier; I have not used GitLab.)

When we do this kind of merge, we can now delete the name `feature`, just as with any other merge.  Commits `I-J` remain findable because of the merge commit.

But instead of a true merge, we can run `git merge --squash`.  This makes a new commit that we can draw this way:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H------S   <-- main (HEAD)
```

New commit `S`, our squash-merge commit, has only *one* parent: `H`.  The *snapshot* in `S` is the same as it would be for merge commit `M`, but `S` *does not connect back to the feature branch tip commit*.  So if we now delete the *name* `feature`, we get:

```
          I--J   ???
         /
...--G--H--S   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Commits `I` and `J` will now eventually go away!

#### Hence a squash merge might have discarded the build files

If you used a squash merge, rather than a real merge, the original sequence of commits—where you added and then deleted the build files—is no longer relevant on the main line (`master` or `main` branch).  If you've also deleted any *names* by which you could find those commits, the originals may well be gone by now.

The process of removing stale, unreferenced commits is called *garbage collection*.  You can force a garbage collection with `git gc`.  However, all commits get a certain grace period (by default at least 14 days) so even if commits are "ready to be removed", it can still take 14 days for a `git gc` to remove them.  You can speed this up with `git gc --prune=now`, but this may not help if there are *reflog* entries, which generally protect commits for at least *30* days.  You can get rid of reflog entries with `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` but this removes *all* safety backup information, so it's generally not a good idea.  Mostly you should just let Git do this on its own.

#### Hosting sites throw in extra wrinkles

When you use a hosting site like GitHub or GitLab and make Pull Requests or Merge Requests, you're also using their add-on databases.  These add-on databases may refer to commits, and in order to do so, they may add their own secret (hidden / internal) names for commits that keep them alive.

These kinds of names *may* prevent some or all commits from ever being garbage collected.  Whether, when, and how you can get around this depends on the hosting site.